# Styling active <li> element in a horizontal menu.

Tags: jquery, css

I am having a sample navigation menu , [have a look](http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/kt4yb/)
I want that the effect which I am having on the `hover` , I want the same effect when a `link` is clicked.The current link should have the same effect.I think I need to use `jquery` for that.Sorry if I am not explaining my question well.
Any suggestions are welcome , thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the pseudo-class `:active`. (Its CSS for clicked state) and optionally `:focus` . If you want the effect to stay you gonna need to do it with jquery:

```
$(function(){
  $(".menu").on("click", "a", function(){
    $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
  });
});
```

then you can add you effect to the active class... Here is a demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/meo/kt4yb/6/

Or you could simply use the `:visited` pseudo class, if the your links point to different URL's

Comment: it is working but how the class be removed from other elements , because only one link can be active at a time right?

Comment: when href='#' it works well , but if I use href="ABC.aspx" it just doesn't work , can u help.

Comment: @freebird i have modified the example and the code.... but you should realy use the :active pseudo class..

Comment: but it doesnot show the effect when a different href is used.Works for href="#"

Comment: ...please update your question then, its not very clear what your goal is

Comment: will change it but any idea as to why it is happening

Comment: @freebird this is because if its something else then #. Then the page reloads and all the JS and CSS is reset... Unless you are setting some cookies, parse the window.location its gonna be hard to achieve in the frontend...

Comment: do you mean that I should set the class according to my url and match the name of the menu item and page , is it.

Answer (score 2):

change the selector from `hover` to `focus`. You dont even need to use jquery

**Edit** : I have edited the fiddle.

see this http://jsfiddle.net/kt4yb/3/

Comment: i want that when any of the link is clicked that effect should stay , which will help the user to identify which link he has clicked.